# Is there a way to group rankings in SQL Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to get the ranking or grouping to count like in the custom_ranking column:

[image]

I want it to count the rank like in the row custom_ranking, but everything I keep trying is counting it in the current_ranking row.

I am currently using this:

```
,row_number() OVER (partition by custID, propID  ORDER BY trans_type desc, record_date desc) AS RANKING
```

Comment: Your code and your data do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, this would be:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by custid order by propid)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: Is there a way to have it order those grouped rankings by the one with the most recent activity on the record_date?